# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: occurs after multiple uses of a program

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, docker, noclassdeffounderror

I have a service that runs from a docker container which runs just fine for about an hour or so, and then suddenly throws a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. After reading up on these errors it seems it is often an issue in initialization. However, my service runs just fine at first -- including using the class that suddenly can't be found!

In fact this particular class needs to be initialized in order for the service to start correctly. This is a multithreaded application running on Spring.

What are some reasons for a class to go missing after being used?

Comment: where is said class located, is that part of library jar or main jar ?

Comment: The class is in the library jar, it is a dependency of the main service.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

This was a weird memory issue. The garbage collector was picking and deleting the class that my program was looking for. It would boot up and run fine, but once it sat idle for 30 minutes or so the GC would destroy the class it needed. Womp! Gave my program some more memory and it works like a dream now.